# Three different branches for three different environments in GIT

Tags: git, git-branch, environment

Working with GIT and three different environments, like development, preproduction and production, it might happen that you have three different versions of software in the three environments. So I would say I should have three different branches always reprensenting the three different enviroments to make fixes. Let's say "master" for production, "dev" for development and "pre" for preproduction. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: What is *"right"*? Do you really need three different *versions*, rather than externalising any differences as configuration?

Comment: This seems like one of those "primarily opinion-based" and/or "too broad" questions. With Git, there's rarely one right way for anything. (Often plenty of *wrong* ways :-) )

Comment: Indeed I would do it this way, but think about whether you really need preprod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that's the way it should a work. A single version of the software should move from dev then to staging and finally to production assuming some set of criteria are cleared at each stage.

With your setup, suppose you find an error in "staging" branch, what will you do? You can't move it back to dev since that would be the dev branch.

Comment: Yes, its very common to have in dev and staging environment the same software but if its different and in dev you have installed version 1.3, in staging you have 1.2 and in production you have 1.1 and as you say you find and error in "staging" environment, what would you do then if you dont have that branch for version 1.2?  You have master for version 1.1, you have branch dev for version 1.3 but if you dont have another branch, how to fix version 1.2?

Comment: Different branches then but this has nothing to do with environments. If you 've released 1.0 and are working on 2.0, Staging will have 2.0-rc1 (or something) while dev will have the same version. As you find issues, you'll bump versions to 2.0-rc2,3 etc and finally, put 2.0 on the production.

Answer (score 2):

I think the three ENV branches should follow this flow: *stage*-->**dev**-->**prod** and they should be always clean.

Check this [link](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/branching-best-practices.html)

Comment: dev happens locally, stage happens afterwards on a production clone. dev -> stage -> prod